# App Engine datastore Model for ranking a 4 player game

Tags: python, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

Hi there I'm trying to learn the app engine datastore by modeling a db to store user rank and game scores for a 4 player game.

The write throughput will be low, so I'm trying to optimize for reads, as there will be lots of queries to show things like:

- Get the top 100 players by rank
- Show the Game details (participant players and scores) for the last 10 games played by any players
- Show the Game details (participant players and scores) for the last 10 games played by a certain player

I'm thinking of using a listproperty populated with player keys on the Many side, like this:

```
  class Player(db.Model):
      username = db.UserProperty()
      rank = db.IntegerProperty()

  class Game(db.Model):
      date_played = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

      players = db.ListProperty(db.Key) 
      #this will always have 4 participant player keys

      scores = db.ListProperty(db.IntegerProperty)
      #the 4 game scores corresponding to the 4 participating players
```

I have a gut feeling that using the parallel ListProperties for players and scores under the Game class is not very efficient, **can you see any drawbacks in this approach? Is there a better way?**

I thought of using a separate relationship class that stores reference properties to both games and players, but that seems a bit like overkill, and makes queries more complex.

thanks
pmanacas

Comment: have you seen the [ranking library](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/) that the google code jam team wrote? it's really solid. see the [blog post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/01/google-code-jams-ranking-library.html) for details.

Comment: Hey ryan yes i saw that ranking library, in the end my project needed something much more simple. I ended up storing a score in each Player object that gets updated after each game, then when i want to display a leaderboard i just fetch all the Players and sort them by the score. This works because i have a smallish list of Players that wont grow much over time.

Answer (score 0):

from a database design perspective, I think your best approach for rankings is still the log-aggregate-snapshot approach.  In this approach you will have three basic model components:

1. Player profile data and other auxiliary data for the ranking system.  Read/write mostly.
2. Records of final scores in games.  This will be append-only.  Updates will not be permitted
3. Snapshot/summary of scores by time-frame.  For example, you might do weekly and monthly snapshots for historical data and be able to generate a leaderboard based on current statistics either rolled forward from, a snapshot summary or generated independently.  Snapshots are append-only and once a period of time has a snapshot attached you can no longer insert games/scores into a closed period.

One of the advantages of this is you can generate historical reports quite quickly and quite well.  For example if you are generating snapshots even based per week, you can generate monthly ratings by summing up the whole weeks and then adding the partial weeks' raw results into it, meaning aggregating no more than a few days' data to generate such a report.  Yearly rankings could be generated based on monthly rankings.